Why does Shulchan Aruch not use the term חלף
A knife that is used for Shechita is also called a חלף. Why doesn't the Smach and Shulchan Aruch use this word and instead use the regular term סכין שחיטה?

Perhaps because that term is only a כינוי, and in books of law you want to be clear about what you are referring to

@larry909 apparently according to the link I posted in the question, the term חלף is already from tanach.

yes, but in the link you posted you can see in the answer there that the term חלף itself is a כינוי. Meaning, translated literally it doesn't translate to knife.

As far as I can see over there, translated literally it does mean knife

It would seem to me, neither does the Mishneh Torah. Except for the name of one of the rooms in the Temple compound (and the commentaries explaining the name), do any sources in the Talmudic literature actually use 'חלף', when talking about a slaughtering knife (סכין שחיטה)? Does any Halakhic source use it?
